# PHP Header redirects falling through if statements

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers

I have some code to log how many password attempts have been tried that looks like this:

```
<?php
/* Access denied */
$_SESSION['error'] = "invalidlogin";

if (isset($_SESSION['tries']))
{
    if ($_SESSION['tries'] == 5)
    {
        //TODO: Redirect somewhere nicer and more descriptive
        header("location:/index.php");
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['tries']++;   
    }
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['tries'] = 0; 
}

header("location:/login.php");
?>
```

I know it is counting up to five and then stopping cuz I tested it by echoing $_SESSION['error'] on login.php

PHP never redirects when it hits

```
header("location:/index.php");
```

But it always keeps going and then redirects to

```
header("location:/login.php");
```

How can I get PHP to redirect as soon as it hits the index.php redirect?

Do I just set a boolean after the index.php redirect and check it on the login.php redirect?

**EDIT:** To clarify, I have already defined a session_start(); don't worry about that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
header("location:/index.php");
exit();
```

Answer (score 5):

A redirect only takes effect AFTER it's been sent to the client's browser and the browser initiates a new request (which terminates the current request). Simply calling header() doesn't initiate the redirect - your script will keep running until it exits normally, the connection is closed and the webserver shuts down the script, or you explicitly terminate execution.

if you want a redirect header to take effect immediately, you need to terminate the script, which causes a flush of any pending output (including the redirect header):

```
header("Location: ...");
exit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) it's good practice to call `exit();` after calling `header();`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your entire method is flawed. You should not do a redirect upon login failure, that might cause security issues. You should see to it that your script includes the proper sub-page within the same request.

Although, technically the answer to your question is, as stated, to use exit().

Comment: I know, that's why the todo is there, it's just a quick write up for now

Answer (score 0):

u Forgot to start the session !!!!
use exit or die after header("location:/index.php"); to do not continue the rest